# Como exibir/ocultar, individualmente, div replicada em AngularJS, utilizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

*[SIMULAÇÃO utilizando JSFiddle no final da descrição do problema]*

A seguinte função realiza a inserção de alguns elementos utilizando AngularJS:

```
$scope.addItem = function (user){
    $scope.items.push({
    nome: $("input[name='nome']").val(),
    email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
    soma: sum++
  });
  user.nome = '';
  user.email = '';  
};
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para cada item inserido existe uma tabela de atributos que deve ser preenchida.

Contudo, ao selecionar um estado nessa tabela, o estado da outra tabela é alterado igualmente.

Como manipular/controlar individualmente cada ação, da tabela Atributos (exibida via Modal), utilizando javaScript?

Script que exibe/oculta os campos de acordo com o estado:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {         
    $('#estado').on('change', function() {
        if($(this).val() == "GO"){
            $('#insc-go').show();
            $('#insc-to').hide();
        }
        if($(this).val() == "TO"){
            $('#insc-to').show();
            $('#insc-go').hide();
        }
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $('#insc-to').hide();
            $('#insc-go').hide();
        }
    });
})
```

> Simulação: https://jsfiddle.net/xs2102e5/

Comment: Uma opinião, a utilização do jQuery so está complicando seu entendimento. Tente utilizar somente Angular, será mais fácil e você irá ter um entendimento melhor do que é preciso fazer.

Comment: Concordo com a posição do @BrunoWego. Tente utilizar as ferramentas nativas do Angular para isso, como `ng-if`.

Comment: Certo, @BrunoWego, poderia me auxiliar como devo substituir o jQuery por Angular nesse caso específico?

Comment: Conseguiram entender o meu problema através da simulação no JSFiddle?